# Why folders and files disappear suddently

Tags: files, filesystem, directory, system-settings

Hi I do not know why all folders and files disappear. Please see the below screenshot. In order to confirm the Ubuntu system still can work well, I created another file "test.tet". As we can see, the file created is there. But why other folders and files disappear? Thank you!

Here are some screenshots:

[image: click here to see screenshot]

Comment: Huh. That's... odd. What exact OS version are you using?

Comment: Try opening the files app or whatever GUI file manager you use. Check if the folders are there. If not, then they must be deleted! Try looking at recycle bin, if your directories are there. Also [edit] to post the output of `ls -l` `ls -a` and `ls -CFL`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am new to this field. I only can follow the command you provided. I did not deleted any things. all I did are to create ansible to do automation at the platform. Please see the below output:

Comment: @davidy They're deleted! The only option you have is to open a GUI file manager and look for the files there :-(

Comment: Please [edit] to include the output of `history 15`

Comment: **Wait! Are you using Kali Linux?** From the screenshot I can say the terminal is of Kali Linux! Note: only official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on Ask Ubuntu.  VTC

Comment: as default `ls` hides `.` files .... and as you can see `-a` exposes them

Comment: Wasn't that what OP asked for? can't see anything deleted. If he adds. e.g., `ls -al` files will be exposed but in a list

Comment: Can you show a command that I can enter to show what version I am using?

Comment: I followed a protocol from Udemy to install Ubuntu and then install ansible

Comment: @davidy you can use `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Anyone can help to share a link which shows basic linux commands? many thanks

Comment: admin1@Lenovo10:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: @davidy think youtube is a good source for beginner tutorials [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhlWCja5JwE), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxuRxtrO2Ag)

Comment: @davidy For a tutorial, Ubuntu [has an official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/command-line-for-beginners#1-overview). It is rather verbose, and doesn't cover much more than the absolute basics, so I don't suggest it. But you can check it out. If you like books, I like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Learning-bash-Shell-Programming-Nutshell/dp/0596009658/) quite a bit. [Microsoft made an introduction to Bash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/bash-introduction/) that is quite good (but skip/ignore the Azure bit at the end)